# Update using case and select from different table

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to do an SQL update where I want to set the value of the column being updated depending on the value in a second table. The script below shows what I'm trying to do but so far I haven't hit on the correct syntax.

```
 update sometable set name = 
  case
   when (select newid from lookuptable where oldid = name) <> null then newid
   else name
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE T
SET
  T.name = L.newid
FROM sometable T
INNER JOIN lookuptable L
  ON L.oldid = T.name
```

There's no need for a coalesce or an outer join, because you're only interested in updating the rows that match.

Also, when comparing a value to null, you should always use `X IS NULL` or `X IS NOT NULL` rather than `X = NULL` or `X <> NULL`, because equality (and inequality) operators always return false for null values.